# Android Can't write into firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

i know there's a lot of simial questions but even with that my problem still persists.

I'm tryna learn how to develop an android by following lot of tutorials on yt for a school project.

I'm triyng to make a register page for a dating app, as i register the user everithing goes well and the data get saved in the autentication of firebase but the database remanes empty and i get no errors or anything similar.

Does anyone knows how to fixs this?

If yes i would really appreciate your help and be grateful to you for all my life.

**Register.java**

```
  package com.example.tippys;

  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.RadioButton;
  import android.widget.RadioGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
   import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

   import java.util.Objects;

public class RegistrazioneUtente extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button Registrazione, Indietro;
private EditText Email, Pass, Nome;
private RadioGroup bSesso;
private RadioButton Check;

private FirebaseAuth Autenticazione;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registrazione_utente);

    Autenticazione = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrazioneUtente.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(RegistrazioneUtente.this, "Registrazione effettuata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;

            }
        }
    };

    Registrazione = findViewById(R.id.registerBottone2);
    Email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    Pass = findViewById(R.id.password);
    Nome = findViewById(R.id.nome);
    bSesso = findViewById(R.id.sesso);
    Check = findViewById(R.id.check);
    Indietro = findViewById(R.id.goback);


    Registrazione.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String inp_email = Email.getText().toString();
            final String inp_pass = Pass.getText().toString();
            final String inp_nome = Nome.getText().toString();

            int selezione = bSesso.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            final RadioButton inp_sesso = (RadioButton) findViewById(selezione);
            final RadioButton lastRadioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.check);

            if (inp_nome.isEmpty()) {
                Email.setError("inserire nome");
                Email.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if(selezione ==-1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selezionare sesso",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (inp_email.isEmpty()) {
                Email.setError("inserire email");
                Email.requestFocus();
                return;

            }
            if (inp_pass.isEmpty()) {
                Email.setError("inserire password");
                Email.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
                Autenticazione.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(inp_email, inp_pass)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(RegistrazioneUtente.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegistrazioneUtente.this, "Registrazione non riuscita, riprovare...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Users users = new Users(inp_nome, inp_email, inp_pass);
                                    String userId =Autenticazione.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();/*.getReference().child("users").
                                            child(inp_sesso.getText().toString()).child(userId);*/
                                   DatabaseReference ref=database.getReference().child("users").child(userId);
                                   ref.setValue(userId).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                           System.out.println("Completata");
                                       }
                                   });                             
                                  
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

        });


    Indietro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(RegistrazioneUtente.this, SceltaLoginRegister.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Autenticazione.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Autenticazione.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
};
}
```

Here's the **Build.gradle(appName)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

**Build.gradle(:app)**

```
 dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')


implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'

 }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `ref.setValue(userId)` operation?

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: yes, i tried to attach an addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()... but i dont get the message frome the completelistener.

Comment: as you can see i modified the code, and i also added the logcat

Comment: Have you also tried to log a potential error?

Comment: Yes i tried, i saw that the database reference like wasnt pointing to the correct link of my database, so i changed my .json and deleted build folder and everything worked fine. However thanks for the help :)